# Multiple .on() events

Tags: javascript, jquery

My app has a feature that when you click the <kbd>new data</kbd> button, HTML is loaded to the page via ajax.  Because I am using AJAX, all events I want to add has to be bound using the `on()` method.

There are 4 `on('click')` functions that are bound to 4 different HTML elements:

```
// save data
$('#container').on( {
    click: function() {
       // save code here            
    }
}, "a.save_data" );

// cancel data
$('#container').on( {
    click: function() {
       // cancel code here            
    }
}, "a.cancel_data" );

// edit data
$('#container').on( {
    click: function() {
        // edit code here            
    }
}, "a.edit_data" );

// delete data
$('#container').on( {
    click: function() {
        // delete code here
    }
}, "a.delete_data" );
```

Each of these functions share multiple jQuery wrappers to select certain elements within the HTML:

```
$(this).closest('div.content_wrap');
$(this).closest('div.Content');
```

**Please note:** The reason I am using selectors such as `$(this).closest()` is because the user has the ability to add the same HTML multiple times on to the page.

First, is there a better way to organize all of the `on()` functions?  Maybe combine them into one object OR create a function?

Second, because all 4 functions use the same jQuery wrappers, is there any way to declare them in a variable globally somewhere, so i don't keep retyping them.  I wasn't able to figure out how declare variables with `$(this)` and apply it to more than one function.

To me, how I am doing it doesn't seem very DRY and I was wondering if someone can help me better organize this.

Comment: See [this question/answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16483/jquery-multi-functional-event-delegate/16494#16494) (/shameless self-promotion)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, that was informative...I was able to follow, but wasn't really able to apply it to what I was doing, but I did find a way to set it up so I don't have so much repetitive code...It's under EDIT in my post if you have any additional feedback...Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd probably do it (basically, it's the same as in the answer I linked to in the comments, I'm just adding it here for clarity)

```
var handlers = {
  save_data:   function (event, content, wrap) {
    // save code
  },

  cancel_data: function (event, content, wrap) {
    // cancel code
  },

  edit_data:   function (event, content, wrap) {
    // edit code
  },

  delete_date: function (event, content, wrap) {
    // delete code
  }
};

$('#container a').on('click', function (event) {
  var klass = this.className,
      content,
      wrap;

  if(typeof handlers[klass] === "function") {
    content = $(this).closest("div.Content"),
    wrap    = $(this).closest("div.content_wrap");
    handlers[klass].call(this, event, content, wrap);
  }

  // you want to always "absorb" the click event, you can
  // do so here or in the if-block above
  //   event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can write the handler functions just like you'd write them in your orginal code (i.e. `this` will refer to the right element, etc.). However, the click event handler will pass along the the `content` and `wrap` arguments, so you don't have to have code to select those elements in every handler function.

Of course, if your links have multiple classes, the `className` trick won't work. That's why I'd advocate (as I do in the answer I linked to) using a `data-*` attribute if possible.

Comment: Hey thanks for this again, much appreciated...I am actually returning back to this and I had a question...See my code above, I added a new edit...It's just a simple test...I did exactly what you have except I took out the event object, the `if (typeof...)` statement and the call() method...I assume the if statement was just for security sake, but I can't figure out why you need the call function, I was able to run the code without it and get the same results.  Also, why did you add the event object?

Comment: Also, I tested this with data being pulled in via ajax and I  noticed that without declaring the element I am clicking within the `on()` arguments, the `on()` functionality didn't work, but once I replaced it with `live()`, it did work...Which I know has been deprecated...

Comment: @elgarcon The `typeof` check is there to make sure that the handler actually exists and is a function. If you try `handlers["xyz"]()`, and `handlers["xyz"]` doesn't exist or isn't a function, you'll get an error and JS just stops executing. The point of `call` and passing the event obj, is so the handler functions can be _exactly_ the same as if you added them to the elements the normal way: `this` will be the element the event occurred on, and the 1st argument is the event obj.

Comment: @elgarcon Not sure what you mean by the `on` vs `live` stuff. But if things stop working when you remove things, well, don't remove things. jQuery's `on` function works, so the problem must be on your end. Don't know what else to tell ya.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
function manipulateData($action){
    $('#container').on( {
        click: function() {
            switch(action){
                case "save" : saveData();
                    break;
                case "delete" : deleteData();
            }
        }
    }, "a." + action + "_data" );
}
```

Also, see Flambinos comment

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to help...I came up with something similar and posted it in my post under EDIT...My thinking there is, because I am binding 4 different functions to 4 different elements, I just wanted a way to cut back on the repetitive code.  What I have done allows me to use the same variables for all events and also allows to write 'click' and 'return false' only once ...Any improvements to this that you know of?