# Multiple jQuery events on one element with different functions and target selectors

Tags: jquery, array

According to this two questions: [[1]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/jquery-different-way-to-write-multiple-click-functions) and [[2]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/jquery-javascript-refactoring-multiple-on-events)

I need a way to combine these two methods of handling the event attachment in jQuery.

```
$('selector').on({
    mouseenter: function() {},
    mouseleave: function() {},
    mousedown:  function() {},
    mouseup:    function() {}
});
```

I prefer the previous method but need something like the following to work with "live"-events. (The problem is, that the next pattern kills the clarity if the code will be a bit larger and even if there're comments between the handlers, it breaks the code.):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'selector1', function(){})
           .on('mouseleave', 'selector2', function(){})
           // this comment breaks the chain
           .on('mousedown',  'selector3', function(){})
           .on('mouseup',    'selector4', function(){});
```

However, since there's no real world example to do it like this?:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: 'selector1': function() {},
    mouseleave: 'selector2': function() {},
    mousedown:  'selector3': function() {},
    mouseup:    'selector4': function() {}
});
```

...I've ended up with this simple `on`-wrapper function: https://gist.github.com/4191657

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.act = function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.each(function() {
            for (var i = args.length; i--;) {
                $(this).on(args[i][0], args[i][1], args[i][2]);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now the usage is quite simpler:

```
$(document).act(
    ['mouseenter', 'selector1', function() {}],
    ['mouseleave', 'selector2', function() {}],
    ['mousedown', 'selector3', function() {}],
    ['mouseup', 'selector4', function() {}]
);
```

As @Joonas [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604582/multiple-jquery-events-on-one-element-with-different-functions-and-target-select/13604628#comment18778266_13604628) that this funtion improves anything. I had the need to came up here with a new question.

So my question, have you any thoughts, suggestions or improvements to [this](https://gist.github.com/4191657) function? Or is there maybe a better solution to handle this problem?

Comment: I don't agree that `$(document).on().on()` is any less clear than your last example. Also, comments between the handlers don't break the code, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/xXQnC/

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Joonas and @AlexeyLebedev. The 2 questions you link to were about different handlers for different selectors, but the event type was always "click". Like a math equation, when one part of the equation is constant, you can make some shortcuts. But if you want to have different handlers for different selectors _and_ different event types, well, that's exactly what jQuery already gives you with `.on()`.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Nice! I think there was another problem then... In view of that fact were my questions probably unnecessary :P

Comment: @yckart the comment *might* be breaking the chain because you're not `"using strict";` and the browser assumes a semicolon at the line before the comment.

Answer (score 2):

- Try placing the comments inside the callback instead to avoid breakage. I also do this on `if-else` statements as well so comments remain uniform.
- Event maps are better when appending multiple event handlers to the same selector.
- If you want a bit readability, move the handlers away from the attaching procedure. That way, they look clean

So here it is in the end:

```
//handlers

function selector1handler(){
    //comment here
};

function selector2handler(){
    //comment here
};

function selector3click(){
    //comment here
};

function selector3mouseover(){
    //comment here
};

//add handlers

$(document)
    .on('mouseenter', 'selector1', selector1handler)
    .on({
        click : selector3click,
        mouseover : selector3mouseover
    },'selector3')
    .on('mouseleave', 'selector2', selector1handler)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's already what i did ;) However see my [comment](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19250/multiple-jquery-events-on-one-element-with-different-functions-and-target-select/19251#comment30816_19250) to @AlexeyLebedev